# Ansible check if key in complex dictionnary

Tags: loops, dictionary, ansible

I have complex dictionary structure and I want to check if a subkey is defined. I don't even know if this is possible..

Here's what my dict looks like:

`config:
  1:
    client: ubuntu
    network_setup:
    - routed
    ports:
      sw1: null
      sw2:
        client: 1/0/2
        lte: 1/0/5
  2:
    client: archlinux
    network_setup:
    - bridged
    ports:
      sw1:
        client: 1/0/4
      sw2: null
...`

Note: lte key could not be defined!

What I want is to check if lte is defined in the config dict. Ideally I would need to loop over each entry in `config` using a loop.

I will maybe wrote a custom plugin because this sounds really hard to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's a list, you'll have to loop over it and you can try this condition

```
- debug: var=test_item.ports.sw2.lte
  when: test_item.ports.sw2.lte is defined
  with_items: "{{ config }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: test_item
```

the when condition would check if the variable is defined.